# WinUI 3 ContextFlyout crashing application without exception

Tags: winui-3

I recently updated the SDK version to the latest to and since then (i think...) any contextflyout crashes the application, both in debug mode and the installed app. Sometimes you see the cursor change into a progress ring and after a second or two the application crashes. Sometimes it gives me a Win32 exception and asks me to attach a debugger.

In the event viewer I can see that the faulting module is:
Faulting module name: Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll, version: 3.1.4.0, time stamp: 0xac5fca29

If I go back to a previous commit where everything was fine, the application also crashes.

In another WinUI 3 project, there is no problem with either the older SDK version or the new one.

How to figure out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the bin/obj folders and setting back the SDK from 1.4.231008000
to an older version in this case 1.3.230502000 fixed the problem.

Since the context menu's are working in another project with the new SDK it cannot be just the SDK. Maybe it is some combination of other referenced packages.

Comment: I'm glad you have got your solution and thank for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: Will do, I can do it in 3 hours.. :)